# how to continue the request in mod_wsgi after processing the request

Tags: mod-wsgi

After processing the request in a mod_wsgi module, I want to continue the request as it was supposed to without the module. How to do that ?

def application(environ, startResponse):

// do some processing

then continue the request

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to perform some task after the response has been sent, see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/RegisteringCleanupCode

Doing such tasks in process can be problematic. You are better off submitting details into a separate task system such as Celery, Redis Queue or Gearman and let it handle it. That way the request handler thread is released to handle other requests and you don't reduce the capacity of the WSGI server as far as handling HTTP requests is concerned.

If this is not what you are asking, you need to explain it a bit better as your description is a little confusing.